# Why doesn't Perl's SUPER call use the arrow method?

Tags: perl, oop

I noticed that when you call a superclass's methods, you need to do something like this :

```
my $self = $class->SUPER::new();
```

Why isn't that:

```
my $self = $class->SUPER->new();
```

Comment: Geo, if you want to learn the nitty gritty details of objects in perl, pick up a copy of Damian Conway's Object Oriented Perl http://www.manning.com/conway/  It goes into great detail on different ways to use Perl's OOP features.  It has everything from basic blessed hashes to dynamic method generation, to exotica like blessed coderefs.  It is a very well written book.  But also check out Moose.  For many, if not most, things Moose is the right way to do Perl OOP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect because `$class->SUPER->new()` would normally be the same as `$class->SUPER()->new()`. But there isn't a `$class->SUPER()` function, and its not clear what that would return.

On the other hand, `$class->Foo::Bar` has always been a valid way to call a method directly by full name, so making a special package-like thing — `SUPER` — fits in better. (I suspect that you could actually implement `SUPER` as a package, and maybe it historically was, I don't know)

PS: Take a look at the `mro` package, and `$self->next::method`. Also, take a look at Moose if you're going to do serious OO work in Perl.

Comment: I want to understand the stuff behind before I will use Moose.

Comment: Check out _A Gentle Introduction to Moose_ http://www.catalyzed.org/2009/06/a-gentle-introduction-to-moose.html

Comment: @Geo, You only *think* you want to know more. I can honestly tell you that you are better off not knowing that, until you come across it.

Answer (score 13):

Method calls have a number of forms:

Calls method, possibly inherited:

```
->method()
```

Explicitly calls sub Package::method, whether that's in the inheritance tree or not:

```
->Package::method()
```

Explicitly calls the referred-to sub, whether that's in the inheritance tree or not:

```
->$coderef()
```

Calls the method that would have been called by `__PACKAGE__->method()` if there were no sub method in `__PACKAGE__` (N.B. the class or object on the left of `->` is irrelevant):

```
->SUPER::method()
```

Any of the above, depending on the contents of `$method`:

```
->$method()
```

(Legal even under `use strict;`.)

While the first form is the most common, it's worth learning about the others and how they work.

Answer (score 13):

In short, SUPER isn't a method. It's a virtual package. It's documented in [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) under the "Method Invocation" section.

Note, however, that SUPER bases itself on the current package, not the package of the instance you used it with.

Answer (score 7):

To add to what derobert said:

You're calling 'new' in the 'SUPER' namespace but passing it the object (or string), '$class'.

You don't *have* to use SUPER, as you can give the full package name of the parent (useful in cases of diamond inheritance):

```
sub init {
   my $self = shift;
   $self->ParentClass1::init();
   $self->ParentClass2::init();
}
```

Comment: Other trivia: You can actually do `$self->TotallyUnrelatedClass::init()`, though its probably best not to!