# How is SUPER pseudo class is resolved in perl?

Tags: perl, super

I am new to perl and I was reading up different concepts and came across SUPER.I have few doubts .
How is the SUPER pseudo class is resolved in perl? Its not clear in perlobj.
Can anyone help me understand it

Comment: What problem do you have with the `SUPER` pseudopackage? Be aware that it depends on the package it is used in, not on the type of the object that a `SUPER` method is called on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an overriden method in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186455/what-is-an-overriden-method-in-perl)

Comment: i want to know some basic points about super and how it is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the section title "How SUPER is Resolved" on [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Inheritance).

Comment: This references the "perlobj" section of the documentation which the OP has already stated doesn't have the information they want. (Although they haven't stated what information they want either).

Answer (score 2):

SUPER isn't really even a pseudo-class.  Calling it such may lead to thinking you can do things you can't with it.

`->SUPER::methodname` simply calls the method that would have been called by `__PACKAGE__->methodname()` if there were no sub method in `__PACKAGE__` (N.B. the class or object on the left of `->` is irrelevant).  (quoting myself in [Why doesn't Perl's SUPER call use the arrow method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385511/why-doesnt-perls-super-call-use-the-arrow-method/1386495#1386495))

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean MRO (method resolution order)? The "Method Resolution Order" section in `perldoc perlobj` describes the specification.